# 'setuptools' module not contained in python 3.4?

Tags: python, python-3.4

I was trying to import `setuptools` in `Python3.4` as following,

```
>>> from setuptools import setup
```

But I got the `ImportError: No module named 'setuptools'`.

My current version of `Python3.4` is `Python 3.4.0b1 (default, Nov 29 2013, 16:37:17)`, and it is installed using `MacPorts`.

So there is no `setuptools` module contained in Python 3.4 Standard Library, right? and I need to install `setuptools` module through `pip`?

**Update:**

`setuptools` is not in the standard library. But I cannot install it through `pip` because `pip` need `setuptools` installed first. `MacPorts` contains `py34-setuptools @2.0.2` port and I can install `setuptools` through it.

Comment: I think that setuptools are generally not in the standard lib ...

Answer (score 5):

`setuptools` has never been a part of the standard lib. You'll always to download it separately.

For 3.4, download [`setuptools`](https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-2.0.2.tar.gz#md5=101b0829eca064fe47708039d66fc135) - (This is the compressed download link!), extract it and install it via:

```
python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to install it yourself. If you've got a completely empty environment in a new python installation, have a look at [the official install instructions](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/2.0.2#installation-instructions).

Answer (score -2):

It works for me, but I'm using 3.4b2 on a Linux Mint system:

```
$ /usr/local/cpython-3.4/bin/python
Python 3.4.0b2 (default, Jan  5 2014, 13:53:24)
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from setuptools import setup
>>>
```